# Alternative to heredoc, for continuation from the next line for php code, like it is slash in c language?

Tags: php, string, syntax, heredoc

I have a long query

```
 $s = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name,type,
            (select count(opinionid) from fe_opinion where actor=name) as countopinion,
            (select count(commentid) from fe_comment where actor=name) as countcomment,
            (select count(commentid) from fe_reply where actor=name and replyto<>null) as countreply, 
            (select count(voteid) from fe_vote where actor=name and replyto<>null) as countvote,
            (select count(voteid) from fe_vote where actor=name and replyto<>null and vote=1) as countagree,
            (select count(voteid) from fe_vote where actor=name and replyto<>null and vote=0) as countdisagree
            from fs_actor where name=:name");
```

and It gives me a syntax error when I write it like this in multi line. I am unsure about the compiler because i didnt execute it. Is it supposed to work in this format or should I use heredoc?

How can I continue writing a string from next line? Should ı do it by continuing to next lineby pressing enter? Should I use heredoc or Is there a special new line character?

I've found this example in phpdoc

```
echo 'You can also have embedded newlines in 
strings this way as it is
okay to do';
```

so now I think my syntax error is something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark here, are you sure it's not that last comma after `countdisagree` that's giving you a syntax error?  You don't put a comma after the last part of the SELECT, and you might not have realized you put it there, I know I've done that quite a bit myself when breaking up a long SQL query, and it will give a syntax error if it's there because it's expecting another statement to select from.

SQL queries, multiline or otherwise, should only give a syntax error if there actually is one, so if you get a syntax error, you can bet that you have one.  You could break that up so you only have one word on each line and it won't give a syntax error.

Comment: yes phpdoc says it's ok to divide string into lines. my syntax error must be that or something else. i corrected the comma now.

Comment: Yes I have no problem now. I added a reevant phpdoc quote at the end of my question.

Answer (score 1):

There's no line-continuation character in PHP. You should use Heredoc:

```php
$s = $dbh->prepare(<<<'EOQ'
  SELECT name, type,
    (SELECT COUNT(opinionid) FROM fe_opinion WHERE actor = name) AS countopinion,
    (SELECT COUNT(commentid) FROM fe_comment WHERE actor = name) AS countcomment,
    # ...
    FROM fs_actor WHERE name = :name"
EOQ
);
```

The single-quotes around `EOQ` here are what PHP inexplicably calls ["Nowdoc"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) syntax, which is the same as Heredoc but isn't parsed--the equivalent of using `$s = 'Hello $world';` vs. double-quoted `$s = "Hello $world";`--which might save you a couple milliseconds somewhere down the line (but, incidentally, seems to throw off SO's syntax highlighting).

Your only (reasonable) alternative in PHP--other than storing your queries elsewhere--is to use string concatenation, which gets pretty ugly:

```php
$s = $dbh->prepare(
  'SELECT name, type, ' .
  ' (SELECT COUNT(opinionid) FROM fe_opinion WHERE actor = name) AS countopinion, ' .
  ' (SELECT COUNT(commentid) FROM fe_comment WHERE actor = name) AS countcomment, ' .
  // ...
  ' FROM fs_actor WHERE name = :name'
);
```

...which is pretty ugly and requires you to mind your spaces.